# Enable exact multi word search for node titles with the jstree search plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jstree

I use the **jstree search plugin** ([documentation](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/search)) to search for multiple IDs in the title fields of my HTML tree.

I took the original jstree [code](http://code.google.com/p/jstree/source/browse/trunk/jquery.jstree.js?r=236) (line 3398) and changed it as suggested [here](https://github.com/vakata/jstree/issues/10) to enable multi word searching in the title fields of the tree.

It works fine for "title contains" queries (e.g. title *ID:40857332* of node x and title *ID:408* of node y contain the search word *ID:408*) but I'm at loss how to change the code in order to find only exact matches (e.g. title *ID:408* of node y matches the search word *ID:408* exactly).

The function gets called like this:

`$("#my_html_tree").jstree("search", search_words);`

with the following configurations:

`"search" : {"case_insensitive" : true, "search_method": "jstree_title_contains_multi"}`

The variable "search_words" is a string containing several IDs:

```
var search_words = "ID:4 ID:7 ID:3188";
```

The format of the HTML tree nodes:

```
<li id="3188"> <a title="ID:3188">Tree node 3188</a></li>
```

**This is my changed code:**

```
$.expr[':'].jstree_title_contains_multi = function(a,i,m){

    var word, words = [];
    var searchFor = m[3].toLowerCase().replace(/^\s+/g,'').replace(/\s+$/g,'');
    if(searchFor.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
        words = searchFor.split(' ');
    }
    else {
        words = [searchFor];
    }
    for (var i=0; i < words.length; i++) {
        word = words[i];
        if((a.getAttribute("title") || "").toLowerCase().indexOf(word) >= 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

};
```

How must I change the code in order to enable searching only for exact matches?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following solution:
Instead of using

```
if((a.getAttribute("title") || "").toLowerCase().indexOf(word) >= 0)
```

I use

```
if((a.getAttribute("title") || "").toLowerCase() === word )
```

Answer (score 1):

It's cleaner to use the id attribute and not the title. You can even use both.

**Configuration:**

```
"search" : {"case_insensitive" : true, 
           "search_method": "jstree_codigo_descripcion"}
```

**Search call**

```
var codigo = "0102";
var descripcion = "sdf";
jQuery("#arbol").jstree("search",cod +"-"+ desc);
```

**Tree**

```
<div id="arbol">
  <ul>
    <li><a>01</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>0101</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a id="010101" title="foo">010101 foo</a></li>
            <li><a id="010102" title="bar">010102 bar</a></li>                 
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a>0102</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a id="010201" title="asdf">010201 asdf</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**The new search function**

```
   $.expr[':'].jstree_codigo_descripcion = function(a, i, m) {
        var searchFor = m[3].toLowerCase();
        var params = searchFor.split('-');
        var codigo = params[0];
        var descripcion = params[1];

        // attribute id start with codigo
        // attribute title contains descripcion

         if (codigo.length > 0 && descripcion.length === 0) {
            if ((a.getAttribute("id") || "").toLowerCase().indexOf(codigo) === 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (codigo.length === 0 && descripcion.length > 0) {
            if ((a.getAttribute("title") || "").toLowerCase().indexOf(descripcion) >= 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (codigo.length > 0 && descripcion.length > 0) {
            if ((a.getAttribute("id") || "").toLowerCase().indexOf(codigo) === 0 &&
                    (a.getAttribute("title") || "").toLowerCase().indexOf(descripcion) >= 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    };
```